# Submit form using CURL

Tags: php, curl

How do you submit a form using curl that has no name attribute on submit button?

For example, the target site has the following submit button:

```
<input id='some' value='value' type='submit' >
```

This is what I have :

```
$post_data['name'] = 'xyz';
$post_data['some'] = 'value';

foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
            $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }
        //create the final string to be posted using implode()
        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

    $ch = curl_init($web3);
        //set options
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
          "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        //set data to be posted
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
        //perform our request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: The submit button itself doesn't have to have any name attribute - only the fields themselves.

Comment: But then how is it going to submit it? I edited the code.. Can you give an example

Comment: You have to send the Post Request to that URL of the Response where you get the Page.

Answer (score 3):

You (usually) do not need to encode `$post_data`, and the code below **will** submit the form.

The button is not necessary. When `curl_exec` runs, the server receives the equivalent of a filled form (provided that `post_data` is correct).

If the action does not proceed, either some field is missing, or maybe something in the session is. Try opening with cURL the same page that *displays* the form, then submitting the form.

```
$post_data['name'] = 'xyz';
$post_data['some'] = 'value';

$ch = curl_init();
//set options
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
      "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Note -- this will encode using www-form-data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $web3);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**UPDATE**

So let us see what happens normally and what happens with cURL:

```
   Browser                          cURL
1. Goes to www.xyz.com/form         curl_exec's a GET on www.xyz.com/form
2. Server sends HTML                Server sends HTML
3. User types in fields             We populate $post_data
4. User clicks "SUBMIT"             We run curl_exec and POST $post_data
5. Browser contacts server          cURL contacts server
6. Browser sends fields             cURL sends fields
7. Server acts upon request         Server acts upon request
8. Profit                           Profit
```

The code above only implements phases 3-6. It is possible that phase 2 also sends a session cookie and sets some data, which are required by phase 7. So, you need to also implement phase 1 with another curl_exec (GET method, probably, this time), before being able to successfully execute the following phases.

Comment: He was already setting _a_ url with `curl_init($web3);`

Comment: Oopsie. Well, then I can't see why it shouldn't work, unless $web3 was wrong somehow, or a field was missing. The fact that "the form gets filled" seem to indicate that the server recognizes the data, it just doesn't proceed. Either some field is still missing, or some session information is.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: I think I was not specific enough with my problem. This is what I am trying to accomplish: I am sending a curl request to a form (on xyz.com/form) that has input fields and a submit button. I want to be able to fill the form and click on submit button which will then submit the form to (xyz.com/submit).

Comment: Okay. You need the content of the ACTION field of the FORM, that should be your $web3 variable; and all the fields. `curl_exec` is the equivalent of "clicking on the submit button".

Comment: I want to be able to do it from the form page and not going straight to submit page.

Comment: The program is "stuck" on phase 4 (CURL). It is not posting to submit page.

Comment: How do you know this? What instrumentation are you using to verify what is really happening, and what data is it returning?

Comment: I have commented this code: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); so it shows me the page where the program is stopped.

Comment: I'm very sorry to have been unable to help you. My answer above always works for me; I usually send the same data the browser would send (as inspected by Firebug on Firefox), and that's enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. I am going to look at Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

simply don't provide the name of that input form field - that what a browser will actually do for you.

Comment: So you are saying that if I do this $post_data[''] = 'value'; It will submit the form?

Comment: you don't need to set it in that way, in fact you don't need to set this 'value' at all. Just fill the rest of form fields into request and send it.

Comment: But then how is it going to submit it? I edited the code.. Can you give an example

Comment: it will work as intended. No submit button is required for sending request from CURL.

Comment: but it is not submitting it.. it just filled the form...

Comment: what do you mean with "just filled the form"? curl_exec($ch); does the trick and post request is sent to server.

Comment: I think I was not specific enough with my problem. This is what I am trying to accomplish: I am sending a curl request to a form (on xyz.com/form) that has input fields and a submit button. I want to be able to fill the form and click on submit button which will then submit the form to (xyz.com/submit).