# POST Data to webpage using cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping

I have read many QA regarding posting data to website search field and press submit button.

I followed below solutions but still no luck.

[Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204915/submit-form-using-curl)[Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937646/javascript-button-click-using-curl)[Example3](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

I want to POST data to for example [this website](http://www.partselect.com/) which search box and button code as follows,

```
<div id="search">
<input type="search" class="text" value="Enter model or part number" id="searchterm_head">
<button class="blue-header-search" type="submit" id="searchbutton_head">Search</button>
<a onclick="if ($('.nav-menu').is(':visible')) 
    {$('.nav-menu').slideUp(200).fadeOut(200)} 
    else {$('.nav-menu').slideDown(200).fadeIn(200);};" 
    class="nav-menu-icon">
<img alt="" src="/assets/images/nav-menu-icon.png">
</a>
</div>
```

But this code is not included in any form and values are submitted by javascript/jquery. 
So is this possible to pass value this kind or search box using `cURL`

I want to fetch product page url and its content.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

### Update

I think I found form tag, but there is no value in action attribute.

```
<form id="MasterForm" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: The url that the data is searched based off has the search term in the link, so you don't need to post anything to the search box.

Comment: how can we search using product number. where is search url .. please post in comment

Comment: /fuzzysearchresult.aspx?term=[term] good luck.

Comment: Hey Matt its pretty good but it shows similar prdocuts also. I want exact product like if product number is 6-918873, it should show same result as we post this in search box

Comment: /Search.ashx?SearchTerm=[term]&SearchMethod=standard

Comment: It is not showing exact product still it is available on website. it shows other products which have similar product number. Where do u get this queries. I checked complete source and inspect element using Firebug but didnt get any link like this.

Comment: Live HTTP headers to check where the ajax requests from jquery was sending data.

Comment: Do you get exact url which return correct product page

Comment: It working fine Matt.. Thanks a lot